# Data is not working outside the request function in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

How to can access $scope.categories outside the promise success function

```
var categoryPromise = $http.get("../rest/mcategory");
categoryPromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config)
{
    $scope.categories=data;   
});

categoryPromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config)
{
    alert("Error");       
});   
alert(JSON.stringify($scope.categories));
```

I got undefined in each time Why? Any way to access outside?

Comment: The promise probably hasn't had time to resolve by the time it gets to the `alert`. Try putting the `alert` inside the `.success` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `$http` call is asynchronous, this means that it doesn't execute in order of your code, the actual order of your code is as following:

1. Initialise categoryPromise `$http`
2. `alert`
3. categoryPromise finishes
4. categoryPromise `success` callback

So if you want to use the data from `categoryPromise` you have to do it in the `success` callback.

---

Side note: don't use `.success`, it's deprecated. Use `.then` instead like so:

```
promise.then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Comment: I need to write this way .Is it correct
 
 
     var categoryPromise = $http.get("../rest/mcategory");
 
    categoryPromise.then(function(data, status, headers, config)
 
    {
        $scope.categories=data;   
  
    });
   
    categoryPromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config)
 
    {
 
        alert("Error"); 
  
    });

Comment: You can do it like this: `$http.get("../rest/mcategory").then(function(data, status, headers, config) { $scope.categories=data; }, function(error) { alert(error) }); `

Comment: after getting $scope.categories can i execute this one in outside success function of categories Is   $scope.categories.id is getting on that   var productPromise = $http.get("../rest/product/"+$scope.categories.id";
 
    productPromise.then(function(data, status, headers, config)
    {
        $scope.products=data;  
  alert(JSON.stringify($scope.products));  
    });
   
    productPromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config)
    {
        alert("Error");       
    });

Comment: <code>var categoryPromise=$http.get("../rest/product");
 categoryPromise.then(function(response) {       
        $scope.categories = response.data;        
    });
    categoryPromise.error(function(response) {
        alert(response.data);
    });</code>

Answer (score 0):

As Martijn points out, if you want to use it for direct modification you'll have to do it into the callback as the XHR request won't be finished.

However if you put this into your `$scope`, it's maybe because you'll use it into your view with data binding into the DOM. In that case Angular is pretty neat because, when the promise will be resolved, at the next `$digest` cycle it will populate with your category object all of the `{{category.strings}}` in your $scope realm.

Would love to post that in a comment but don't have 50 rep.

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is angular hits that url and continues to execute the code after that without waiting for response that's why here maybe url is hit by browser but when execution reached to assign categories it got undefined.

**Solution:**

```
var categoryPromise = $http.get("../rest/mcategory");
categoryPromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config)
{
    $scope.categories=data;   
   alert(JSON.stringify($scope.categories));
});

categoryPromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config)
{
    alert("Error");       
});
```

Comment: Solution 2 won't work if the request is slow, `$timeout` just pushes the function to the next `digest` cycle, don't use that

Comment: Yeah i know i dont use it too more often for learning purpose and to show whats happening i gave this solution.